# How to set HUGO.io landing page?

Tags: hugo, theming

I'm trying to set one of my sub-pages as a landing page in my hugo.io page setup. But all I can find so far is the hint to change the content of the home.html file in my layout folder.
This is not what I want to do, because by this I will duplicate the existing layout file for the sub-page whis is error prone. Is there any Site parameter that sets my sub-page "Portfolio" to be my landing page?

My setup:

```
|content
   |posts
   |about
   |portfolio
      |work1 (This is a page bundle)
      |work2 (This is a page bundle)
          index.md (Page Content File)
      _index.md (List File)
```

My template setup:

```
|layouts
   |_default
      list.html
      single.html
   |portfolio
      list.html
      single.html
   index.html
   home.html
```

So layouts/portfolio/list.html ranges through all my portfolio work. This works fine. The file is used when I navigate to localhost:1313/portfolios.

But for having the same content on localhost:1313/ I understand to duplicate the layoutfile to layouts/home.hmtl -> Is this correct? This seems utterly laborious to me. Is there a more convenient way to tell hugo "use the file content/portfolios/_index.md as my landing page"?

Hope you can help me, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to move the content of `layouts/portfolio/list.html` to a [partial](https://gohugo.io/templates/partials/), then include this partial in both `layouts/portfolio/list.html` and `layouts/index.html`. This way you will not have to duplicate the code you use to list all of your work.

I would also advice you to read the documentation on [order lookup for templates](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/), specifically the section related to the [home page](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/#examples-layout-lookup-for-home-page), as this explains the order of which template files are included.